# Probability of random value in interval

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

We divide an interval [0,1] into k equal parts.

It is clear that the likelihood that a randomly chosen number between 0 and 1 will be in the first subinterval $[0,\frac{1}{k}]$ is exactly $\frac{1}{k}$.
Similarly, it is clear that the likelihood that the randomly chosen number will $not$ be in that subinterval is $1-\frac{1}{k}$.

However, this looks like continuous unform distribution to me. And according to my textbook, the way to calculate probability for that type of distribution is $\frac{1}{b-a}$, where $a, b$ are the limits of the subinterval. This makes no sense to me, as in this case it would yield the probability $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{k}}=k$.

Is this not continuous unform distribution? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You mix up the total interval $[a,b]$ with the subinterval $[0,\frac{1}{k}]$ of $[0,1]$. For a uniform distribution on $[a,b]$ by what do you have to divide its length for it to be a probability distribution ?

Comment: Ah ok. So the $a, b$ in $\frac{1}{b-a}$ refer to the length of $k$ in this case, ie. $a=0, b=k$? Is it correct that it is a continuous uniform distribution?

Comment: You should know that the length of $k$ in the case $a=0,b=k$ is $b-a$ and ***not*** $1/(b-a)$. To answer your last question: every continuous and uniform probability distribution on a finite interval is a simple version of the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$. If $\lambda([a,b])=b-a$ is not one by what do we have to divide it to make it a ***probability*** measure?